# Get Safari version from UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, mobile-safari

How do I get the Safari version from a UIWebView?

If I use the code below, the version is not include in the UserAgent

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
NSString *userAgent = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"navigator.userAgent"];
```

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I read the title and was going to suggesting injecting javascript but you are already doing it haha! Your code should have worked... maybe it doesn't work with mobile safari... Try this `navigator.appVersion`

I also found this code online if it helps:

```
navigator.userAgent.search("Version") + 8
```

Comment: That did not work, the user agent I get does not contain the version number or build number for Safari.

Comment: (`window.navigator.appVersion`)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with WKWebView in Swift 5:

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("navigator.userAgent") { version, error in
        if let str = version as? String {
            print("WEBKIT VERSION " + str)
        }
    }
```

This will give you an AppleWebKit version that you can match up with Safari by scrolling down to the drop down menus on this wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history